# Render markdown as GFM (GitHub Flavored Markdown), therefore preserving line breaks?

Tags: markdown

In particular, I'm trying to render the text in markdown preserving the original line breaks, like in the GitHub Flavored Markdown specifications.

Using `{{ something | md }}` in a template the output contains a line break only if a line ends with two spaces, like in the original markdown implementation.

Some markdown processors (ie Blackfriday, written in Go) call this feature "hardLineBreak".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get good results using `{{ block.myFieldName|nl2br|markdown }}`

Answer (score 1):

There is a Craft [Parsedown](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Parsedown) plugin for Craft which supports Github Flavored Markdown you can use.